# FixtureAdapter with simulateRemoteResponse=false not rendering calculated properties

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Does anyone experience the same issue?

my calculated property is dependent on a belongsTo-related object.
ember: 1.0.0-pre.2-291-g4785901
ember-data: rev11

Issue can be reproduced here ... 
http://jsfiddle.net/smadep/pVqte/13

```
IceEmberApp.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.create({
        simulateRemoteResponse: false
    })
});
```

...

```
<div class="list" id="flatlist">
    {{#each substanceFindings tagName="ul"}}
        <li>{{substanceGroupName}} - {{substance.name}}: {{quantity}} <br />
            ... debug calcProp: {{substance.displayName}}</li > 
    {{/each}}
</div >
```

switch simulateRemoteResponse between true and false and see the difference.

Sorry, there is more stuff in this fiddle as I have a related issue, when I keep simRemResp true.
Then I don't get updates on deeper nested objects being added from Fixture, hence the calculated properties are wrong here, too.

If this is not an issue but my bad understanding and coding style, please accept my apologies!

Comment: I think the correct terminology is *computed* properties. Looking at the fiddle I could not find where you have defined `displayName` computed property. You also seem to be missing a view for the `npsFinding` template. I got lost in that fiddle and cant really figure out what you are trying to do. Hopefully someone with more experience could chime in. Meanwhile, I would suggest cleaning up the fiddle and trying to isolate and pinpoint the problem you are facing.

Comment: Aras, sorry for wrong terminology! but the displayName was/is working, just the data was not fully loaded/"materialized" (whatever the right terminology is in this case) the way I set up the fixtures.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the fixtures for my data were not properly loaded/materialized.

I changed the code to explicitly load the data into the store like

```
IceEmberApp.store.load(IceEmberApp.Substance,'1b9664a6-9a3b-40e1-92ff-f425b590b64b', {
  name: '3,4-methylenedioxymetamfetamine',
  abbreviation: 'MDMA',
  alternativeName: '',
  casNumber: '',
  substanceGroupId: '18d7c284-27a8-4c3e-b855-4de752699782',
  substanceGroupName: 'AMFETAMINE TYPE STIMULANTS',
  substanceGroupWeight: 1.00000
});
```

... and then the computed properties and nested relations were all available, loaded fine.

see my forked jsfiddle for a **working** example ... http://jsfiddle.net/smadep/tYSRf/

well, this is no answer why setting up the fixtures using below

```
IceEmberApp.Substance.FIXTURES = [{
  id: '6ae3880f-7b7a-4db3-a28c-880cf9fac2cc',
  findings: ['8ca9600f-c574-4e6e-a976-47f0a9004d63', ''],
  name: 'test1 β',
  abbreviation: '',
  alternativeName: '',
  casNumber: '',
  substanceGroupId: 'b96e2edb-2bc6-441e-8379-8ad35e14eaf9',
  substanceGroupName: 'NPS Group 1',
  substanceGroupWeight: 1.00000
}, ...
]
```

... was **not working**, but my problem is solved :-)